# How to avoid richfaces 4.3 css classes

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

So, I'm using richfaces 4.3. This messes up my style since 4.3 has a lot of styles of its own. I remember that richfaces 3 had a param you could use in web.xml to prevent the class loading. Is this still possible with 4.3? I tried it out, but didn't work.

Comment: Found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697772/how-stop-richfaces-style?rq=1